# How to avoid "Video Source -> Capture source" selection in OpenCV 2.3.0 - Visual C++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I had a perfectly working OpenCV code (having the function `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)`). But when I modified it to run in a separate thread, **I get this "Video Source" selection dialog box** and it asks me to choose the Webcam. Even though I select a cam, it appears that the function `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` returns null. I also tried by passing the values `0, -1,1, CV_CAP_ANY`to this function. I have a doubt that this **dialog box** causes this issue. Is there any way to avoid this or does anyone have any other opinion?

I've followed the following posts when debugging:

[cvCreateCameraCapture returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197707/cvcreatecameracapture-returns-null)

[OpenCV cvCaptureFromCAM returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749067/opencv-cvcapturefromcam-returns-zero)

**EDIT**
Code structure

```
//header includes
CvCapture* capture =NULL;
IplImage* frame = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    DWORD qThreadID;
    HANDLE ocvThread = CreateThread(0,0,startOCV, NULL,0, &qThreadID);   
    initGL(argc, argv);   
    glutMainLoop(); 
    CloseHandle(ocvThread);    
    return 0;
}

void initGL(int argc, char** argv){    
    //Initialize GLUT
    //Create the window
    //etc
}

DWORD WINAPI startOCV(LPVOID vpParam){ 
    //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); //0 // CV_CAP_ANY

    if ((capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1)) == NULL){ // same as simply using assert(capture)
      cerr << "!!! ERROR: vCaptureFromCAM No camera found\n";
      return -1;
    }    
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
}    
//other GL functions
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's a weird behavior of OpenCV on Windows. Does this happens with OpenCV 2.3.1?

Comment: My version is 2.3.0 (cout<<"OpenCV version:" <<CV_MAJOR_VERSION<<        CV_MINOR_VERSION<<CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION)

Comment: Good, but that really doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a problem that only happens on Windows, an easy fix is to leave `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` on the `main()` thread and then do the image processing stuff on a separate thread, as you intented originally.

Just declare `CvCapture* capture = NULL;` as a global variable so all your threads can access it.

Comment: Have you tried `cvCreateCameraCapture` instead of `cvCaptureFromCAM` ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I couldn't get rid of the above mentioned dialog box, but I avoided the error by simply  **duplicating** the line capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

It was just random. I suspect it had something to do with behavior of Thread. What's your idea?

Thanks all for contributing.