# cvFindContours always returns 0 - OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I'm calling the `cvFindContours` function inside a separate thread that I've created to handle all OpenCV work while another is kept for OpenGL stuff.

I noticed that my `cvFindContours` function always returns 0 when this code is executed inside a separate thread. It worked fine before, when executed in the main thread itself. I used breakpoints and Watches to evaluate value changes. everything else (variables) gets values except for `contourCount` (value: 0).

Any clue?

```
// header includes goes here
CvCapture* capture = NULL;
IplImage* frame =  NULL;
IplImage* image;
IplImage* gray;
IplImage* grayContour;
CvMemStorage *storage;
CvSeq *firstcontour=NULL; 
CvSeq *polycontour=NULL;
int contourCount = 0;   
    
DWORD WINAPI startOCV(LPVOID vpParam){
  
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); // NOTE 1
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);  
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);  
    image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    grayContour = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage (0);
    firstcontour=NULL; 
    
    while(1){
            frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            cvCopy(frame,image);
            cvCvtColor(image,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);     
            cvSmooth(gray,gray,CV_GAUSSIAN,3);
            cvThreshold (gray, gray, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
            cvNot(gray,gray);
            cvCopy(gray,grayContour);
            
            contourCount=cvFindContours (grayContour, storage, &firstcontour, sizeof (CvContour), 
    CV_RETR_CCOMP); 
                            polycontour=cvApproxPoly(firstcontour,sizeof(CvContour),storagepoly,CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,3,1); // Error starts here (Pls refer to stack trace)   
    }
         // goes on...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

     DWORD qThreadID;
     HANDLE ocvThread = CreateThread(0,0,startOCV, NULL,0, &qThreadID);
     initGL(argc, argv); //some GL intitialization functions
     glutMainLoop(); // draw some 3D objects
     CloseHandle(ocvThread);
     return 0;
}
```

NOTE1: these lines had to be duplicated due to the error mentioned at [How to avoid "Video Source -> Capture source" selection in OpenCV 2.3.0 - Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081062/how-to-avoid-video-source-capture-source-selection-in-opencv-2-3-0-visual)

Environment:
OpenCV 2.3.0
Visual C++ 2008

**EDIT**

**Traces**

> opencv_core230d.dll!cv::error(const cv::Exception & exc={...})  Line 431 C++
>
> opencv_imgproc230d.dll!**cvPointSeqFromMat**(int seq_kind=20480, const void * arr=0x00000000, CvContour * contour_header=0x01a6f514, CvSeqBlock * block=0x01a6f4f4)  Line 47 + 0xbd bytes C++
>
> opencv_imgproc230d.dll!**cvApproxPoly**(const void * array=0x00000000, int header_size=88, CvMemStorage * storage=0x017e7b40, int method=0, double parameter=3.0000000000000000, int parameter2=1)  Line 703 + 0x28 bytes C++
>
> Project.exe!startOCV(void * vpParam=0x00000000)  Line 267 + 0x24 bytes    C++

All this stuff boils down to the function `CV_Assert( arr != 0 && contour_header != 0 && block != 0 )` in `cvPointSeqFromMat` and it fails since `arr` it requires is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `contourCount` is not doing what you think it's doing. From the `contours.cpp` source file:

```
/*F///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    Name: cvFindContours
//    Purpose:
//      Finds all the contours on the bi-level image.
//    Context:
//    Parameters:
//      img  - source image.
//             Non-zero pixels are considered as 1-pixels
//             and zero pixels as 0-pixels.
//      step - full width of source image in bytes.
//      size - width and height of the image in pixels
//      storage - pointer to storage where will the output contours be placed.
//      header_size - header size of resulting contours
//      mode - mode of contour retrieval.
//      method - method of approximation that is applied to contours
//      first_contour - pointer to first contour pointer
//    Returns:
//      CV_OK or error code
//    Notes:
//F*/
```

You are getting `CV_OK == 0`, which means it successfully ran. `cvFindContours` does not return the number of contours found to you. It merely lets you known if it failed or not. You should use the `CvSeq* first_contour` to figure out the number of contours detected.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please have a look at the traces I've added above

Comment: Unfortunately the comment block has betrayed you. Please read the source code "contours.cpp". `return count;`