# OpenCV failing to open camera

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, camera

I have an OpenCV program that is supposed to use a webcam (in this case the built in laptop camera). The program compiles fine without error but when I run it the program seems to hang on the line:

```
img_scene = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

I have a different program that access the camera in the same fashion so I don't understand as to why this program seems to be having trouble.

Full capture code from non-working program:

```
Mat captureThread() {
  if(captureOpen == false){
    img_scene = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(img_scene, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(img_scene, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
  }
  while(1) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(img_scene);
    if(image.empty()) {
      continue;
    }
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return gray;
  }
}
```

This is the code that is being used in a different program that is working as expected:

```
  img_scene = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
  cvSetCaptureProperty(img_scene, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
  cvSetCaptureProperty(img_scene, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
  while(1) {
    imageFrame = cvQueryFrame(img_scene);
    if(imageFrame.empty()) {
      continue;
      cout << "image frame is empty" << endl;
    }
    cvtColor(imageFrame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

What is causing the non-working program to have trouble access the camera? I have also tried plugging in a USB camera and setting `cvCaptureFromCam(-1)` but it does not work either.

EDIT: 
The non-working program uses multiple threads whereas the working program does not.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081062/how-to-avoid-video-source-capture-source-selection-in-opencv-2-3-0-visual

Comment: I'm not getting the same dialog box option as in that question nor does the solutions provided in that question solve my issue.